# Programa que devuelva el total de letras por palabra en una lista

Tags: python-3.x, bucles

Quiero hacer programa que me devuelva el total de letras por palabra en una lista es decir: `(hola, pedro) ->(4,5)`, sin embargo, me está contando todo

```py
lista = ["hola, pedro"]

print(lista)

contar_letras = []

for palabras in lista:
    contar_letras.append(len(palabras))
    

print(contar_letras)
```

output:

```
['hola, pedro']
[11]
```

Answer (score 1):

Hola tu lista esta definida con un solo string completo "hola, pedro"

Cambialo de esta forma con cada palabra entre comillas

```
lista = ["hola", "pedro"]

print(lista)

contar_letras = []

for palabras in lista: contar_letras.append(len(palabras))

print(contar_letras)
```

Y la impresión quedaría así

```
['hola', 'pedro']
[4, 5]
```